# Что такое дескриптор зависимостей в контексте Maven?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Наткнулся на определение и не могу понять значение фразы дескриптор зависимостей.

> Starter-пакеты представляют собой набор удобных дескрипторов зависимостей, которые можно включить в свое приложение.

P.S Тема связана со Spring boot starters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это значит в этом проекте не будет своего кода/библиотеки. Там будет только файл проекта (pom.xml / build.gradle), который подключает набор библиотек, взаимосовместимый и решающий некоторую задачу.

Например, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-tomcat